# Saving an object in mongodb

Tags: meteor

I am trying to save variant options as an object, something like that:
{'1' : {optionTitle: 'title', optionPrice: 12}, '2': {....}}
//schema

```
RestMenuVariants.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    restRefId: {type: String},
    createdBy:{type: String},
    title: {type: String},
    options: {type: Object},
    sortId: {type: String, optional: true},
    createdAt: {type: Date}

}));
```

//part of the method addMenuVariantItem

```
return RestMenuVariants.insert({
            restRefId: restId,
            createdBy: Meteor.userId(),
            createdAt: new Date(),
            title: title,
            options: options,
            sort_id: sortId
        });
```

// part of the event for loop which creates the object

```
  variantOptions[i] = {optionTitle: $(element).val(), optionPrice: $(elementPrice).val()};
}
```

// and calling the method

```
Meteor.call('addMenuVariantItem', this._id, this.createdBy, variantTitle, variantOptions, function(error, result){.....})
```

I don't get any check or other errors, the variant is saved but when I look for the item at the console i see that the options is an empty object:
//var cursor = RestMenuVariants.findOne({_id: id});
//console.log(cursor.options)

```
Object {}
```

What am I missing? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `variantOptions` is being created as an array but your schema only expects an object.

Change:

```
options: {type: Object}
```

to

```
options: {type: [Object], blackbox: true },
```

in your schema definition.

The `blackbox: true` option tells simple-schema to ignore the structure of the objects being put into the options array.

Also note that an array is != a nested object with numbered keys as you have in your description. You won't get:

```
{
  '1': {optionTitle: 'title', optionPrice: 12},
  '2': {....}
}
```

Instead you'll see:

```
[
  { optionTitle: 'title', optionPrice: 12 },
  {....}
]
```